# Recursion in Java enums?

Tags: java, recursion, enums

I've been trying for 3 hours and I just can't understand what is happening here.

I have an enum 'Maze'. For some reason, when the method 'search' is called on this enum it's EXTREMELY slow (3 minutes to run). However, if I copy the same method to another class as a static method, and I call it from the enum 'Maze' it runs in one second!

I don't understand why? is there any problem with recursive methods in Java enums?? What am I doing wrong?

```
public enum Maze
{
    A("A.txt"), B("B.txt");

    // variables here...

    Maze(String fileName)
    {
        loadMap(fileName);
        nodeDistances = new int[nodes.size()][nodes.size()];
        setNeighbors();
        setDistances();
    }

    ... more methods here ...

    private void setDistances()
    {
        nodeDistances = new int[nodes.size()][nodes.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
            setMax(nodeDistances[i]);
            // This works!!!
            TestMaze.search(nodes, nodeDistances[i], i, 0);
            // This DOESN'T WORK
            //search(nodes, nodeDistances[i], i, 0);
        }
    }

    public void setMax(int[] a) {
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }

    public void search(List<Node> allNodes, int[] distances, int curNodeIndex, int curDist)
    {
        if (curDist < distances[curNodeIndex])
        {
            distances[curNodeIndex] = curDist;

            for (Node n : allNodes.get(curNodeIndex).getNeighbors()) {
                search(allNodes, distances, n.getNodeIndex(), curDist + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class TestMaze
{
    public static void search(List<Node> allNodes, int[] distances, int curNodeIndex, int curDist)
    {
        if (curDist < distances[curNodeIndex])
        {
            distances[curNodeIndex] = curDist;

            for (Node n : allNodes.get(curNodeIndex).getNeighbors()) {
                search(allNodes, distances, n.getNodeIndex(), curDist + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding some disgnostic output to see what parameters get passed to the recursive calls, and where the most time is spent...

Comment: yes the problem is still there even if I make it static :S

Comment: *Why* are you using an enum instead of a class?

Comment: I know it works with a class, but I just want to know why this is happening. I'm just stubborn to fix this!

Comment: I just moved everthing to a class with 2 public static final objects (singletons), and still doesnt work from the same class!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This strange behaviour seems to be related to JIT. It seems to be that **methods work slower if they were JIT-compiled during initialization of their classes** (i.e. if they were frequenty called from `static` initializers, it also happens in the OP's case, because enum values are instantiated during initialization).

Here is a small test:

```
public class Test {
    public static final long N = 40;

    static {
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        computeStatic1(N);
        System.out.println("computeStatic1 in initializer: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));

        Test x = new Test();
        t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        x.compute1(N);
        System.out.println("compute1 in initializer: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));

        computeStatic2(10); // Not enough to launch JIT
        x.compute2(10); // Not enough to launch JIT
    }     

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        computeStatic1(N);
        System.out.println("computeStatic1 in main: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));

        Test x = new Test();
        t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        x.compute1(N);
        System.out.println("compute1 in main: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));

        t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        computeStatic2(N);
        System.out.println("computeStatic2 in main: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));

        t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        x.compute2(N);
        System.out.println("compute2 in main: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));
    }

    private long compute1(long n) {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) return 1;
        else return compute1(n - 2) + compute1(n - 1);
    }

    private static long computeStatic1(long n) {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) return 1;
        else return computeStatic1(n - 2) + computeStatic1(n - 1);
    }

    private long compute2(long n) {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) return 1;
        else return compute2(n - 2) + compute2(n - 1);
    }

    private static long computeStatic2(long n) {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) return 1;
        else return computeStatic2(n - 2) + computeStatic2(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Results (Sun JVM):

```
> java Test
computeStatic1 in initializer: 4360
compute1 in initializer: 4578
computeStatic1 in main: 4359
compute1 in main: 4610
computeStatic2 in main: 2859
compute2 in main: 2859
```

JIT disabled:

```
> java -Xint Test
computeStatic1 in initializer: 20578
compute1 in initializer: 21656
computeStatic1 in main: 20250
compute1 in main: 21391
computeStatic2 in main: 20250
compute2 in main: 21375
```

In IBM J9 VM this behaviour is observed only for `static` methods:

```
$ java Test
computeStatic1 in initializer: 5053
compute1 in initializer: 2488
computeStatic1 in main: 5044
compute1 in main: 2473
computeStatic2 in main: 2597
compute2 in main: 2489
```

Answer (score 0):

One obvious question is, do the two variants of search() both produce correct results?

My best guess is that you're running into a class load order problem.  This is because your search routine is kicked off as a side-effect of the enum's constructor.  Since you didn't post the full code I can't say for sure, but try this:

```
Maze(String fileName)
{
    //show when the individual enum values get constructed
    new Exception("constructor for " + fileName).printStackTrace();

    loadMap(fileName);
    nodeDistances = new int[nodes.size()][nodes.size()];
    setNeighbors();
    setDistances();
}
```

... and see if you get different results when you call the enum's `search` method vs. the static version in the other class.